# In Romans, does Paul vary how he identifies "the Gospel" in a way which also identifies "His Son" and "the Christ" as God?

Tags: greek, romans, christology, authorial-intent

In Romans Paul uses the term εὐαγγέλιον, "Gospel" or "good news" 9 or 10 times (some manuscripts have "blessing" in 15:29).
[image]

Paul first calls himself an apostle of the **Gospel of God**, then says he serves God in his spirit in the **Gospel of His Son**. He concludes the letter saying he a minister of Christ Jesus to the Gentiles in the service of the **Gospel of God** and says he has fully proclaimed from Jerusalem to Illyricum the **Gospel of Christ**.

Paul used a pattern at the beginning and near the end of the letter:

```
1:1                      1:9
Gospel of God            the Gospel of His Son
εὐαγγέλιον θεοῦ          τῷ εὐαγγελίῳ τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ

15:16                    15:19
the Gospel of God        the Gospel of the Christ
τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ θεοῦ   τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ Χριστοῦ
```

In considering the parallelisms in this pattern, has Paul varied how he identifies "the Gospel" in a way which also identifies "His Son" and "the Christ" as God?

Comment: Not necessarily, but in so many other places he regards Christ as Lord whom he worships, i.e. treats in the same level as the Father.

Comment: A word of a prophet is a word of God, that doesn't mean the prophet is God. This is the fallacy of association.

Comment: @Michael16 There are two separate issues. One is conveying the relationship between prophets, or between prophet and apostle. The other is describing the content of the message. For example, OT will often have phrases like *the word of the LORD* or *the burden of the LORD* or *God spoke* or *the LORD said*. Regardless of how a specific message was given to the prophet, it is understood as coming from "God." IOW God = LORD.

Comment: if A = B and A = C, then B = C. Sure. What are A, B, and C in this case?

Comment: @TonyChan A= Gospel, B = God, C = Christ, so God = Christ.

Comment: Which verse says that Gospel=God?

Comment: @TonyChan The "=" signs are simple expression to display the logical conditions found in the words Paul chose. τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ θεοῦ identifies εὐαγγέλιον, which he initially said was εὐαγγέλιον θεοῦ (1:1). Next Paul chooses τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ Χριστοῦ, which he initially said was τῷ εὐαγγελίῳ τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ (1:9).  If there is only one gospel, no further adjective is necessary. But, he wants to make the point he is not proclaiming a new gospel, but the same one found in the prophets of the Holy Scripture, hence εὐαγγέλιον θεοῦ, which is sufficient.

Comment: Gospel=God. "Gospel" is interchangeable with "God"?

Comment: Having added one adjective which is sufficient, what is the purpose of adding other different means of identifying the one Gospel of God? No one disputes τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ (1:9) and τοῦ Χριστοῦ (15:19) presents the equality B = C...so what reason does  Paul have to unnecessarily complicate that which requires no further identification?

Comment: I'd suggest that you raise this as a separate OP: Gospel=God?

Comment: @TonyChan If have modified the question to address the essence of your comments. Unless you are disputing His Son = The Christ, the question is clear and should be fine as it stands.

Comment: I see that it is better than before. Still, you need to distinguish between informal parallelism from formal transitivity. I agree that Paul was suggesting the deity of Christ in an informal manner :)

Comment: @TonyChan And why would Paul insert an informal suggestion in this theological masterpiece?

Comment: Good question. By informal, I meant not according to first-order logic. Paul was not formally trained on transitive relations. He was, however, well-versed in parallelism which is what I called informal.

Comment: Formally speaking, A||B  ⊬ A=B.

Comment: @RevelationLad In Romans, does Paul use additions to the describe the ... . Please clarify "additions".

Comment: @TonyChan That is a good suggestion to make the question more specific. Thank you.

Comment: By "imply", do you use it in the everyday English sense or the technical 1st-order logical sense of material implication (⇒)?

Answer (score 6):

In the words of a famous song, "*This land is your land, this land is my land ...*"  However, that does not make you equivalent to me.

It is true that Paul speaks of one faith and Gospel, etc -

- Eph 4:4-6 - There is one body and one Spirit, just as you were called to one hope when you were called; one Lord, one faith, one baptism; one God and Father of all ... [This is the famous seven-fold unity]
- Gal 1:6, 7 - I am amazed how quickly you are deserting the One who called you by the grace of Christ and are turning to a different gospel— which is not even a gospel. ...

Thus, I strongly agree that there is only one Gospel.  However, it is a logical fallacy that the existence of a single true Gospel does not mean that it cannot be "possessed" by more than one person.

For example, I have a single father and so does my brother.  I can talk about my father and so can my brother but that does not make me the same as my brother, ie, we are not the same person but both have the same father.  The same is true of the Gospel.

The Bible compounds this even more with the following considerations.  We have:

**The Gospel of God**

- Rom 15:16 - to be a minister of Christ Jesus to the Gentiles in the priestly service of the **gospel of God**, so that the Gentiles might become an offering acceptable to God, sanctified by the Holy Spirit.
- 2 Cor 11:7 - Was it a sin for me to humble myself in order to exalt you, because I preached the **gospel of God** to you free of charge?
- 1 Thess 2:8 - So yearning over you, we were pleased to have imparted to you not only **the gospel of God**, but also our own lives, because you have become beloved to us.
- 1 Thess 2:9 - Surely you recall, brothers, our labor and toil. We worked night and day so that we would not be a burden to anyone while we proclaimed to you the **gospel of God**.
- 1 Peter 4:17 - For it is time for judgment to begin with the family of God; and if it begins with us, what will the outcome be for those who disobey **the gospel of God**?

**The Gospel of the Grace of God**

- Acts 20:24 - But I do not account my life of any value nor as precious to myself, if only I may finish my course and the ministry that I received from the Lord Jesus, to testify to **the gospel of the grace of God**.

**The Gospel of the glory of the blessed God**

- 1 Tim 1;11 - according to **the gospel of the glory of the blessed God**, with which I have been entrusted.

**The Gospel of God concerning His Son**

- Rom 1:1-3 - Paul, a servant of Christ Jesus, called to be an apostle, and set apart for the **gospel of God**— the gospel He promised beforehand through His prophets in the Holy Scriptures, **regarding His Son**, who was a descendant of David according to the flesh,

**The Gospel of His Son**

- Rom 1:9 - God, whom I serve with my spirit in preaching the **gospel of His Son**, is my witness how constantly I remember you

**The Gospel of Jesus Christ, the Son of God**

- Mark 1:1 - This is the beginning of the **gospel of Jesus Christ, the Son of God**.

**The Gospel of Christ**

- Rom 15:19 - by the power of signs and wonders, and by the power of the Spirit of God. So from Jerusalem all the way around to Illyricum, I have fully proclaimed the **gospel of Christ**.
- 1 Cor 9:12 - If others partake of the authority over you, should we not more? But we did not use this right. Instead, we bear all things, so that we should not place any hindrance to the **gospel of Christ**.
- 2 Cor 2:12 - Now when I went to Troas to preach **the gospel of Christ** and a door stood open for me in the Lord,
- 2 Cor 9:13 - Because of the proof this ministry provides, the saints will glorify God for your obedient confession of the **gospel of Christ**, and for the generosity of your contribution to them and to all the others.
- Gal 1:7 - Evidently some people are troubling you and trying to distort the **gospel of Christ**.
- 1 Thess 3:2 - We sent Timothy, our brother and fellow worker for God in **the gospel of Christ**, to strengthen and encourage you in your faith,
- Phil 1:27 - Nevertheless, conduct yourselves in a manner worthy of **the gospel of Christ**. Then, whether I come and see you or only hear about you in my absence, I will know that you stand firm in one spirit, contending side by side for the faith of the gospel

**The Gospel of our Lord Jesus**

- 2 Thess 1:8 - in blazing fire, inflicting vengeance on those who do not know God and do not obey **the gospel of our Lord Jesus**.

**The Gospel of the glory of Christ**

- 2 Cor 4:4 - The god of this age has blinded the minds of unbelievers so they cannot see the light of **the gospel of the glory of Christ**, who is the image of God.

**The Gospel of your salvation**

- Eph 1:13 - And in Him, having heard and believed the word of truth—**the gospel of your salvation**—you were sealed with the promised Holy Spirit,

**The Gospel of peace**

- Eph 6:15 - and with your feet fitted with the readiness of **the gospel of peace**.

**The Gospel of the kingdom**

- Matt 4:23 - Jesus went throughout Galilee, teaching in their synagogues, preaching **the gospel of the kingdom**, and healing every disease and sickness among the people.
- Matt 9:35 - And Jesus was going throughout all the cities and the villages, teaching in their synagogues, and proclaiming **the gospel of the kingdom**, and healing every disease and every sickness.
- Matt 24:14 - And this **gospel of the kingdom** will be preached in all the world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come.

**The eternal Gospel**

- Rev 14:6 - Then I saw another angel flying overhead, with **the eternal gospel** to proclaim to those who dwell on the earth—to every nation and tribe and tongue and people.

**The Gospel of Paul**

- Rom 16:25 - Now to Him who is able to strengthen you by **my [Paul's] gospel** and by the proclamation of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery concealed for ages past
- Rom 2:16 - on the day when God will judge men’s secrets through Christ Jesus, as proclaimed by **my [Paul's] gospel**.
- 2 Tim 2:8 - Remember Jesus Christ, raised from the dead, descended from David, as proclaimed by **my gospel**,

**Our Gospel = Gospel of Us**

- 1 Thess 1:5 - because **our gospel** came to you not only in word, but also in power, in the Holy Spirit, and with great conviction—just as you know we lived among you for your sake.
- 2 Thess 2:14 - to this also He called you through **our gospel** to the obtaining of the glory of our Lord Jesus Christ.

Thus, the one and only true Gospel is, according to above is "The Gospel of God", "The Gospel of Christ", "The Gospel of Paul", "The Gospel of His Son", "The Gospel of peace", "The Gospel of salvation", "the Gospel of the kingdom", "The gospel of the Lord Jesus", etc, etc.  These are all the one true Gospel but salvation is not equivalent of God and Christ, etc.

Thus, the one and only true Gospel belongs to all who claim it.  This does not make Paul equivalent to Christ or God, etc.  Nor does it make Christ equivalent to God.  That teaching must be derived from other considerations.

**CONCLUSION**

Paul uses the terms "gospel of God" and "gospel of Christ" equivalently.  This same gospel is also called "the gospel of me", ie, "my gospel".  However, that does not imply Christ is equivalent or on the same level as God.

[Note: It is well known on this site that I believe that Jesus is, was and always will be fully God in the highest sense; but that idea cannot be derived from these considerations as shown above.]

Comment: @RevelationLad - Paul uses the two terms, "gospel of God" and "gospel of Christ" and "gospel of me" equivalently.  Nothing can be deduced about Christology from this.

Comment: @RevelationLad - the gospel belongs to all but it also teaches about God and Christ.  Hence the genitives.

Comment: @RevelationLad - are you pushing a barrow here or asking a real question.  It appears to be the former.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131404/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-dottard).

Answer (score 3):

We can’t say for sure what was in Paul’s mind, but he usually made it pretty clear what his stance was on theological issues. You would therefore need to look to other passages to try to strengthen the case that Paul was saying Jesus was God. One could argue that the anarthrous θεοῦ in the first verse is distinguished from the arthrous mention of God and Christ at the end in chapter 15, τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ θεοῦ and τὸ εὐαγγέλιον τοῦ Χριστοῦ. The “divine gospel” is that of God and Christ, identifying them both as God.

A.T. Robertson makes the distinction clear in his treatment of John 1:1 which has “theos” with and without an article, showing how the distinction avoids Sabellian modalism.

> “And the Word was God (kai theos en ho logos). By exact and careful
> language John denied Sabellianism by not saying ho theos en ho logos.
> That would mean that all of God was expressed in ho logos and the
> terms would be interchangeable, each having the article. The subject
> is made plain by the article (ho logos) and the predicate without it
> (theos) just as in John 4:24 pneuma ho theos can only mean “God is
> spirit,” not “spirit is God.” So in 1 John 4:16 ho theos agape estin
> can only mean “God is love,” not “love is God” as a so-called
> Christian scientist would confusedly say. For the article with the
> predicate see Robertson, Grammar, pp. 767f.” (A. T. Robertson, Word
> Pictures in the New Testament, vol. 5, pp. 4-5.

We know from other texts throughout the NT that Christ is God’s Son and that the two terms are referring to the same person. But could we use the logic you are using  to suggest that Christ is God? In other words, is God the same as Christ in the same way that Christ is the same as God’s Son? That would then leads to the incongruity of God being the same as God’s Son. In other words, people could make the equivalency argument (same as) as easily as the equality (not greater or lesser than) one. Paul would obviously be left out of the equation as a mere man and each of his possessive references to the gospel are immediately followed by references to Christ. τὸ εὐαγγέλιόν μου διὰ Χριστοῦ Ἰησοῦ  and τὸ εὐαγγέλιόν μου καὶ τὸ κήρυγμα Ἰησοῦ. It is not his own gospel that he is preaching but that of Christ in that context.

When Paul talks about justification by faith in Romans 3, he is referring to two distinct persons with different roles. God’s righteousness is accessed through faith in Jesus Christ. God overlooks sin (justifies) because of what Jesus did. No equivalency is implied there.

> Rom 3  23 for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,
> 24being justified as a gift by His grace through the redemption which
> is in Christ Jesus; 25whom God displayed publicly as a propitiation in
> His blood through faith. This was to demonstrate His righteousness,
> because in the forbearance of God He passed over the sins previously
> committed; 26for the demonstration, I say, of His righteousness at the
> present time, so that He would be just and the justifier of the one
> who has faith in Jesus.

Another way to understand Paul’s modifications of “good news” apart from random assignments is by making a distinction between the different facets of the gospels Paul is proclaiming even though it ultimately refers to the same Good News of salvation through God and Christ Jesus. The Good News of God is that he has provided a way for all men and women to be reconciled to himself and escape the curse and ravages of sin. The Gospel of Christ is that Jesus is the means by which that happens through his death and resurrection. The Gospel of Paul is the two proclaimed together to both Jews and Gentiles.

> Ro. 1 1 Paul, a bond-servant of Christ Jesus, called as an apostle,
> set apart for the gospel of God, 2which He promised beforehand through
> His prophets in the holy Scriptures, 3concerning His Son, who was born
> of a descendant of David according to the flesh, 4who was declared the
> Son of God with power by the resurrection from the dead, according to
> the Spirit of holiness, Jesus Christ our Lord, 5through whom we have
> received grace and apostleship to bring about the obedience of faith
> among all the Gentiles for His name’s sake, 6among whom you also are
> the called of Jesus Christ; NASB
>
> 1 For I am not ashamed of the gospel of Christ: for it is the power of God
> unto salvation to every one that believeth; to the Jew first, and also
> to the Greek. KJV

The Gospel of Christ, which Paul mostly preached, was a greater stumbling block to both the Jews and the Gentiles as we see from 1 Corinthians.

> 1 Cor 1 23 but we preach Christ crucified, to Jews a stumbling block and to Gentiles foolishness,

That is the gospel that Paul mostly preached. In Romans, the good news of Christ appears more than the good news of God. The Gospel of God is mentioned twice and uses OT terminology and images such as prophets (Ro. 1:1) priests, and offerings.

> Ro. 15 16 to be a minister of Christ Jesus to the Gentiles,
> ministering as a priest the gospel of God, so that  my offering of the
> Gentiles may become acceptable, sanctified by the Holy Spirit.

The Gospel of Jesus Christ is the fulfilment of the mysterious Gospel of God announced by the prophets, and later proclaimed by Paul. If he were obliquely implying anything else, I think we could at least agree that that wasn’t his focus.

Comment: I think this is a very helpful answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

"The Gospel" is, in itself, a massive subject. The Bible speaks of the beginning of this gospel, and the fullness of the gospel, and the gospel by which people are saved, a different gospel that is no gospel at all, the gospel of peace, and the eternal gospel. All of these aspects of the biblical gospel are part of the one gospel.

Then you have mentioned the amazing way in which the Bible identifies this gospel as equally being the gospel of God, and the gospel of Christ. Again - those are not two distinct gospels, but part and parcel of the one gospel.

Because this one, biblical gospel is called "the eternal gospel" (Revelation 14:6) it is what pre-Christian believers knew something about, and believed. Noah, Abraham, Moses and many others had a glimpse of this saving gospel in their day, looking forward to what was to come even though they only knew a little about the Christ who was utterly intrinsic to this good news. Hebrews chapter 11 shows this. Clearly, as the centuries passed and then the Messiah appeared on earth, a huge step forward in understanding the fullness of this gospel happened. Divine revelation was needed to grasp the role of Christ in this good news.

By the last book of the Bible, this same, eternal gospel is to be declared by an angel flying in mid-heaven to all who live on the earth. That gospel message is the start of the gospel; "Fear God and give him glory, because the hour of his judgment has come. Worship him who made the heavens, the earth, the sea and the springs of water" (Rev. 14:6-7).

This is to happen shortly before the wrath of God's judgment comes on the whole world. No longer is the gospel proclaimed by Christians, but now the last chance to be saved is pronounced by an angel. The starting point of the everlasting gospel is to fear God, to give him the glory "because the hour of his judgment has come", and to worship him who made everything.

If people refuse to heed the beginning of the gospel, they will not heed the rest of it, which explains why the gospel is such good news to those who turn to Christ in faith. John the Baptist likewise began with the beginning of the gospel, to prepare Jewish people to turn to Christ. Those who repentantly sought forgiveness and baptism would have started aright, and then get to continue in faith and understanding as they heeded Christ's gospel ministry.

The foundation of the gospel is Jesus Christ, for no foundation can be laid other than what is laid - Jesus Christ (1 Cor. 3:11). That is why ***revelation about just who this Jesus is forms the core of the biblical gospel***. Understand who the biblical Christ is, put faith in him to be saved, and the whole of the good news will change your life. However, ***if a person does not identify the Son of God according to the Bible's revelation, they can only follow "another gospel, which is no gospel at all"*** (Galatians 1:6-9).

Because it is God incarnate who is the foundation of this gospel, to speak of the gospel of God is to simultaneously speak of the gospel of Christ. **But just reading those verses you have listed would not, in itself, lead you to that understanding**. One has to have revealed to them by the guidance of the Holy Spirit showing in scripture just who this Son of God is before the link can be made, which you point out. All that Paul says about the gospel of God and the gospel of Christ makes perfect sense when Christ is seen as God incarnate. However, those who think Jesus to be a creature (and not the one who made everything - John 1:1-14 cf. Rev. 14:7) will never see any such identification of Christ with God.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to comprehend that G'd is considered a king according to **Psalm 47:6-7**:

> Sing praises to God, sing praises! Sing praises to **our **King****, sing
> praises! For God is the King of all the earth; sing praises with a
> psalm! (ESV)

or in hebrew:

> עָלָ֣ה אֱ֭לֹהִים בִּתְרוּעָ֑ה יְ֝הֹוָ֗ה בְּק֣וֹל שׁוֹפָֽר׃ זַמְּר֣וּ
> אֱלֹהִ֣ים זַמֵּ֑רוּ זַמְּר֖וּ לְ**מַלְכֵּ֣נוּ** זַמֵּֽרוּ׃

Since it's a known fact that *bible is the truth*, King David can't say something which isn't true, thus G'd is a King. In the prophet that becomes clearer (**Isaiah 7:14**):

> 14 Therefore the Lord himself shall give you a sign; Behold, a virgin
> shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel. (KJV)

In hebrew we read:

> לָ֠כֵ֠ן יִתֵּ֨ן אֲדֹנָ֥י ה֛וּא לָכֶ֖ם א֑וֹת הִנֵּ֣ה הָעַלְמָ֗ה הָרָה֙
> וְיֹלֶ֣דֶת בֵּ֔ן וְקָרָ֥את שְׁמ֖וֹ **עִמָּ֥נוּ אֵֽל**׃

**עִמָּ֥נוּ אֵֽל** means **G'd is with us**, then to be more precise, an unmarried woman would give birth to man, called **G'd is with us**, and so, clearly she has to be virgin, according to the law.

Then, Paul (who was a Rabbi) was really implying the *holiness* of **Christ** in such a level, that **He is King**, this is, it's not possible to distinguish both ones, the eternal and the who was to come, this happens for the reason again, that **G'd is King**.

The same analogy happens in **Romans** (without the need to quote the verses). If Christ wasn't G'd, He couldn't be called Immanuel, by definition. Now, you could argue that *Gabriel* means *G'd is Strong*, which is true, one of the ten *sefirot* of G'd, however, these are still shadow if compared to the ten *sefirot* together, indeed, it's not that an emanation is with us, but He (G'd) Himself. In other words, G'd Himself went out from his throne and went back by the *humbleness of Him*. Another verse that proves again my point is the following (**John 14:6**):

> Jesus said to him, “I am the **way**, and the **truth**, and the **life**. No one
> comes to the **Father** except through me.

However the **Truth** is **G'd**, also the **life** is **G'd**. The way that the *Good news* were written and other texts, is that one, which doesn't let you to incur in idolatry.